# Eclipse- connecting to svn repository

Tags: eclipse, svn

I downloaded the SVN plugin for eclipse and I am now having trouble connecting to the repository I need.  I have the URL that I should be adding (it works on my school's computer).  However I don't think it is doing what it should be.  I included a picture that shows the pop up window when I try to add a new repository on eclipse.  It is creating a folder inside of my eclipse folder in applications when I attempt to add this.  The dialog on this window looks different than the one that comes up at school.  This particular window will only let me select "file system"?  I believe that is just creating this repository on my own computer?  What do I need to do to connect to a remote repository?

http://s23.postimage.org/e4s7iso7f/screen_capture.png <- pic here

Answer (score 5):

Please follow these steps:

1. Window, Open Perspective
2. Select "SVN Repository Exploring"
3. Once you are there, if SVN Repositories is not showing, go to Window,Show view, and select "SVN Repositories"
4. Now right click on the empty area of the SVN Repositories to have the context menu show up
5. Select "Repository Location"
6. Enter the URL and a label of your choice
7. Enter username and password if necessary and click "Save authentication"
8. Click Finish

I suspect that you are selecting "New Repository" instead of "Repository Location".