# How to completely install and run a SVN Plugin in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I couldn't find a complete tutorial for setting and connecting to a SVN Repository in Eclipse. Most tutorials assume you already have the required plugins installed.

Edit: I am asking for a more detailed, advanced explanation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse- connecting to svn repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300216/eclipse-connecting-to-svn-repository)

Comment: Which version of Eclipse u r using?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is Eclipse Subversive plugin.

There's a pretty comprehensive guide for installation here.

https://eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/gettingStarted/aboutSubversive/install.php